# Circled Background should stay the same size

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So I want to display a number with a circled background. However I don't know the length of the number. My current solution will only show the correct size when I have two digits. How can I ensure, that it will stay the same if I have only one digit?

```css
.circled-background{
  background:lightgreen;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:28px;
}
```

```html
<h1>1 Digit</h1>
<i class="circled-background">1</i>
<br><br>
<h1>2 Digits </h1>
<i class="circled-background">11</i>
<br><br>
<h1>3 Digits</h3>
<i class="circled-background">111</i>
```

Comment: So you wanna keep the bg a circle or you dont mind it becoming a rounded rectangle? Because number with more digits will cause m7ch bigger circles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using width, you can achieve..

```css
.circled-background{
  background:lightgreen;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:28px;
  width:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<h1>1 Digit</h1>
<i class="circled-background">1</i>
<br><br>
<h1>2 Digits </h1>
<i class="circled-background">11</i>
<br><br>
<h1>3 Digits</h3>
<i class="circled-background">111</i>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have done almost, please do the below changes to make it work :)

CSS:

```css
  

  .circled-background{
      background:lightgreen;
      border-radius:100%;
      width:80px;
      height:80px;
    }
.circled-background i {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
     padding-top:35%;
}
```

```html
   

 <h1>1 Digit</h1>
    <div class="circled-background"><i>1</i></div>
    <br><br>
    <h1>2 Digits </h1>
    <div class="circled-background"><i>11</i></div>
    <br><br>
    <h1>3 Digits</h3>
    <div class="circled-background"><i>111</i></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo Need same height as width for the container.

Otherwise the circle border-radius:50%; will try to make round circle of
current squire.

Which will not take shape of circle.

And when your number grow more then 5 digit then you will see that your current solution will break.

Answer (score 0):

```
.circled-background {
    background:lightgreen;
    border-radius:50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: table;
}
.circled-background div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<div class="circled-background"><div>1</div></div>
<br><br>
<div class="circled-background"><div>11</div></div>
<br><br>
<div class="circled-background"><div>111</div></div>
<br><br>
<div class="circled-background"><div>1111</div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ganesh16889/xg576472/

This might help you. Please check this.